# Session variable gets updated automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void btningAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

if(!(txtLOVCode.Text==" "||txtLOVvalue.Text==" "))
           {

            rowid++;
           // DFDLOVlst.Visible=true;
            DataTable dt = createTemptable();
            dt = (DataTable)Session["dfdtemptable"];
           DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
          dr["prociLOV_Id"] = rowid;
          dr["prociLOV_Value"] = txtLOVvalue.Text;
          dr["prociLOV_Code"] = txtLOVCode.Text;
          Boolean isalreadyinLOVlst = false;

          foreach (DataRow chkrow in dt.Rows)
          {
              if (String.Equals(dr["prociLOV_Value"].ToString().Trim(), chkrow["prociLOV_Value"].ToString().Trim(),StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                  && String.Equals(dr["prociLOV_Code"].ToString().Trim(), chkrow["prociLOV_Code"].ToString().Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
              {
                  isalreadyinLOVlst = true;
                  break;
              }

           }

          if (isalreadyinLOVlst)
          {
              this.lblMessage.Text = "LOV value: " + dr["prociLOV_Value"].ToString() + ": " + dr["prociLOV_Code"].ToString() + " already exits";

          }
          else
          {
              this.lblMessage.Text = " ";
              dt.Rows.Add(dr);
              DataTable addedLOV = createTemptable();
            addedLOV = (DataTable)Session["addedLOV"];
            addedLOV.ImportRow(dr); ;
            Session["addedLOV"] = addedLOV;

          }


            DFDLOVlst.DataSource = dt;
            DFDLOVlst.DataBind();
         //   dt.AcceptChanges();

            Session["dfdtemptable"] = dt;

            txtLOVCode.Text = "";
            txtLOVvalue.Text = "";
            MDIngrdientsCode.Hide();
            this.txtLOVvalue.ReadOnly = false;
            this.txtLOVCode.ReadOnly = false;

           }
           else

            this.lblMessage.Text="NO LOV VALUES ENTERED";

        }
```

Here the session variable `Session["dfdtemptable"]` and `Session["addedLOV"]` both get updated twice and their row count becomes 2 for each session variable. But the row count should be 1 for each session variable. But the Session variable gets updated when the other Session variable's updated.
The `Session["dfdtemptable"]` gets updated when `Session["addedLOV"]` is assigned or updated. I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: I do not see any relation between the row count and the number of updates on the Session["dfdtemptable"] variable. I think your problem is that you have a global variable rowid and do a rowid++, which should be a local variable for your method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a problem in `createTempTable` method, although it is not shown here. Seems both your dt (aka dfdTempTable) and addedLov (aka addedLOV) reference the same DataTable.
I suggest you to start in Debug mode and either check rows in both dt and addedLOV tables during execution or compare those two objects using Make Object Id in Debug.Watch window.

Comment: yea..i have the same reference dataTable for both  the tables..
public DataTable createTemptable()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

but den how can i refer the same data table to both session varibles.
            //rowid = 0;
            dt.Columns.Add("prociLOV_Id");
            dt.Columns.Add("prociLOV_Code");
            dt.Columns.Add("prociLOV_Value");
            return dt;
        
        }